# Mule collection aggregator does not return the right sequence of List

Tags: java, mule, esb, mule-studio

I am using collection splitter and collection aggregator on a List. I can see my request List is splitted in the right sequence, and then sent to the subsequent components, however, after using collection aggregator, the sequence of the aggregated List is in a random order. I checked the correlationSeq in every splitted message, they are good. I did tried put resequencer before and after aggregator, but both are not working.

Please advise.

```
    <collection-splitter/>
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="requestProcessor" />
    </component>
    <resequencer failOnTimeout="true" />
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scene the `collection-aggregator` uses an implementation of `org.mule.api.store.ObjectStore` to store the events it accumulates.

Neither the in-memory and persistent default implementations provided with Mule are respectful of the order in which data is stored. So the only option I see without coding too much is to order what's inside the message collection after the `collection-aggregator`.

Comment: Thanks David. I created custom aggregator to order the event, and it worked for me.